# how to get a collection of network traffic

Tags: networking, ns2

I am trying to implement a algorithm for detecting DDoS attacks. For this I require a collection of both legitimate and attacking traffic but I don't know how to get these traffic samples. Please can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use packet sniffer -> Wireshark

Comment: can you tell me more about this. and the thing is that i need a collection of network traffic including both normal and attacking traffic, so that I can implement and simulate it using equations.Will this Wireshark help me doing this?

Comment: Wireshark capture any packet that passes through the NIC, which means that all traffic attacking or not, will be captured depending on the filter you use.  There is no simple explanation on wireshark, you can download and try it, it is free and easy to use.
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: thanks for the help.. can you please tell me something related to calculating entropy of the network traffic in wireshark.

Comment: That's beyond my knowledge, but I found this for you http://www.kaspersky.com/images/Oleg%20Gudkov.pdf